# how to find one value is associated with multiple values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  code     tank      product
  1234     1         MS
  1234     2         HS
  1234     1         HS
  1234     1         HS
  1235     1         MS
  1235     1         HS
  1235     1         MS
  1245     1         MS
  1245     2         HS
```

I want to find how many tanks have multiple products associated with them, in above dataframe e.g for code 1234 tank 1 has Ms and HS as well 
There are 2 cases in above dataframe

My Desired Dataframe would be

```
  code     tank     flag
  1234     1        yes
  1234     2        no
  1235     1        yes
  1245     1        no
  1245     2        no
```

How can I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) for count unique values per groups:

```
df = df.groupby(['code','tank'])['product'].nunique().reset_index()
print (df)
   code  tank  product
0  1234     1        2
1  1234     2        1
2  1235     1        2
3  1245     1        1
4  1245     2        1
```

And then extract column with [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) and set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df.pop('product') == 1, 'no', 'yes')
print (df)
   code  tank flag
0  1234     1  yes
1  1234     2   no
2  1235     1  yes
3  1245     1   no
4  1245     2   no
```